# MySQL group by date DATE_FORMAT() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_completed, "%c/%Y") AS Month, COUNT(*) AS Total_Transactions, SUM(order_total_grand) as Total_Spend FROM `shop_orders` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_completed, "%c/%Y") DESC
```

Which outputs the following table:

[image: Table]

How can I sort the table by date correctly?

Comment: You want ORDER BY to sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't order by the string version of the date.  Order by the original date:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_completed, "%c/%Y") AS Month, COUNT(*) AS Total_Transactions,
       SUM(order_total_grand) as Total_Spend
FROM shop_orders
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_completed, "%c/%Y")
ORDER BY MIN(order_completed) DESC;
```

Strings are ordered as strings, not dates.